# Ruby Selenium send_keys_characters not sending the strings I want

Tags: excel, ruby, cucumber, spreadsheet, rubymine

```
xlsx = Roo::Excelx.new($docs_dir + '/mytestsheet.xlsx')
  xlsx.each_row_streaming do |row|
    send_keys_characters(row)
    step %[I wait for 2 sec]
  end
end
```

I've been struggling with pulling the values from an xlsx file and sending each cell with send_keys_characters into a manual input field on my website; I have 2 issues here and I can't seem to figure out the solutions:

1. it does not pull ONLY the value of the cell I want e.g "test1", "test2", instead it writes one after the other [excel feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3qwf.jpg):
   [#<Roo::Excelx::Cell::String:0x0000000008076b30 @cell_value="test1", @style=0, @coordinate=[1, 1], @value="test1">]
   [#<Roo::Excelx::Cell::String:0x0000000006399800 @cell_value="test2", @style=0, @coordinate=[2, 1], @value="test2">]

How can I pull only the value of the cell and mention it on my input field and then Submit?

2. It needs to pick up the first value and then Submit and continue the scenario and then to return and pick the second value and third and so forth... How can I pick one value at a time and then go to the next step?

Answer (score 0):

This is a ruby / selenium question.

So in essence your problem is looking for the code to enumerate over your objects and send the values you want.

I'm not familiar with Roo, but if they use standard readers then you can just do

```
array.each do |excel_string|
  input_field.send_keys(excel_string)
end
```

This will concatenate all of the values, so your input field will say `test1test2` e.t.c.

If you need to type these in across a set of fields i.e. input_field 1/2/3 I would use `#zip` to create a 2d-array pair

```
text_values = array.map(&:value)
zipped_array = input_fields.zip(text_values)

zipped_array.each do |input_field, value|
  input_field.send_keys(value)
end
```

Comment: thanks, you are totally right, my output is now ["test1"] and then ["test1"]["test2"], so yes it just concatenates them. It does not matter if it's roo or something else as long as we get to the desired result. First, how can I get rid of the brackets and quotation marks and have only test1,test2, test3, test4 etc. 
Secondly, I have only one field, not many, so I think the problem should be way simpler; it should pick the first line from the excel test1 => Search, then second scenario, test2 => Search, test3 and so on. So only one field and to pick the values one by one.

Comment: So you need to reframe your question then. As I solved the original one. If you're looking for sanitizers, look inside the individual map / each enumeration methods. You likely will want something that does #flatten (Reducing a 2d array to a 1d array). Or just casting it `#to_s`